# Reading tar tape with blocking factor 2048 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, tar, dd

I am trying to read a tar tape on CentOS 7 which was written on CentOS 5. I used blocking factor `2048`.

I can read tapes written with blocking factor `1024`, but not `2048`. Attempting to read the tape with `dd` with something like:

```
dd if=/dev/nst0 bs=1M | tar tvf -
```

Doesn't work either, which suggests something different about the st driver.

Any advice?

- Centos 5 is kernel 2.6.18
- Centos 7 is kernel 3.10.0.

Comment: Have you try to use directly `tar` itself? `mt rewind; tar -b 4 tvf /dev/nst0`

Comment: Yes, the command I would normally use would be:  tar tvbf 2048 /dev/nst0

Comment: This may not work because you set for filename 2048. And have you try my way?

Comment: The dd command piped to tar should do the same thing, perhaps more slowly.  Neither one works.  For appropriately written tapes (written with tar cvbf 1024 /dev/nst0) both commands work using tar xvbf 1024 /dev/nst0 or dd if=/dev/nst0 bs=512K /dev/nst0.

Comment: For tar the parameters are given in the same order as the options, so "2048" corresponds to "b" and "/dev/nst0" corresponds to "f".

Comment: For historical reasons there are several different ways the options and parameters can be given to tar.  This has nothing to do with my problem.